# Webkit change background-image using jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, webkit

I don't know why does this code not work on chrome and safari, but in mozilla works fine?

```
$('#id').css('background-image','url(/image.png)');
```

I also tried this

```
$('#id').css('background-image','url("/image.png")');
$('#id').css('backgroundImage','url("/image.png")');
$('#id').css('backgroundImage','url(/image.png)');
```

but still doesn't work.

Comment: Does the network tab show a failed request?

Comment: are you running it locally without using any server?

Comment: epascarello, i don't know how to se that :( . The script in on http://www.2lol.ro/ and turns on when you click the down arrow in the header.

Comment: @Marian07 open console (f12 on windows or ctrl+shift+j) and check

Comment: @A. Wolff i did, but further i do not know.

Comment: The code works, the problem was from an conditional. :)

Answer (score 0):

where do you put the image file (image.png)? If it is in the same directory as in the .html file, you could try this

$('#id').css('background-image','url("image.png")');

Comment: It's not from the image!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('selector').css('backgroundImage','url(images/myImage.jpg)');
$('selector').css({'background-image':'url(images/myImage.jpg)'});
```

The latter example allows for multiple rules. [Check out the API](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for more details.

**Edit:** Make sure your path(s) to your image(s) are correct by inspecting the console. That should tell you if you are getting a 404.